# Unable to open code behind file in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

In an ASP.NET web application using C#, when we double click on design it will go to code behind page (cs file), but problem here is, when we double click on design its going to script of source file. Why it is happening?

Comment: @sravan: I have edited your question to include a VS reference in title and tags. I am pretty sure this is what you want, but if not, do not hestitate to roll back my edit.

Comment: @user260997 did you modify that file by hand?

Comment: It would be helpful for the users that answer your questions and for other which stumble upon your questions to know if you found a correct answer, by checking the right one.

Answer (score 1):

Is there actually a matching .aspx.cs file for the page? Sounds to me like the project you're working on is a Web Site rather than an WebApplication, and the page was created without checking the "Place code in separate file".

Is there anything else in the Script section of the .aspx page? It's possible that once there is code in there, double clicking on the designer will open that instead of the code behind.

Personally, I always avoid double clicking to open the source in-case I accidentally click on a control and create a click event, rather than just opening the code - I prefer to either:

1. Right-click on the designer and "View source"
2. From Solution Explorer open the .cs file directly.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and when I survey my code, I found the problem in the `@page` tag where codefile was not correct.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem after importing an .ascx file into an existing project. I had to import the .ascx.cs and .ascx.designer.cs files on my own too, since otherwise I could not use the "Show Code (F7)" feature of Visual Studio. It would show that the files are all there, but the icon in Visual Studio was a bit grayish.